# How web languages work?

Tags: html, web

I know how general purpose languages like C or C++ work. I mean you write a C or C++ source code and you use a compiler to produce an object or directly exe file which contains machine code for cpu to do the work. But I'm wondering how all web languages work like HTML/CSS/Javascript etc.? I mean how they are executed? who executes them? How are they translated? Because you cant compile web languages like HTML with compiler like gcc and run it... Does the browser have some HTML engine that understands the HTML and then translates it to C or what code?

Answer (score 1):

HTML is not executed, it's *rendered*. HTML *describes* the structure of a document as a hierarchy of elements. The way each element is rendered on screen conforms to certain rules (e.g. "Headers must be displayed as 16pt Helvetica, black bold") and can be altered using style rules. Style rules are specified in CSS, which is another declarative (i.e. that describes) language.

To sum up, HTML and CSS describe *what* should be displayed, not *how* things are done. So you can't compile them to executable code (e.g. with gcc), because there is no sequence of actions in them. They are descriptions, the browser will decide the best course of actions.

On the contrary, Javascript is a general purpose language like C or C++ is. It happens to be the one that all browsers understand. It's executed by the browser, which might even compile it (it's called JIT) and can access and manipulate the page via a set of specific APIs.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very good link: [How browsers Work](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/internals/howbrowserswork/) to answer your question.

The browser's main components are:

**The user interface** - this includes the address bar, back/forward button, bookmarking menu etc. Every part of the browser display except the main window where you see the requested page.

**The browser engine** - the interface for querying and manipulating the rendering engine.

**The rendering engine** - responsible for displaying the requested content. For example if the requested content is HTML, it is responsible for parsing the HTML and CSS and displaying the parsed content on the screen.

**Networking** - used for network calls, like HTTP requests. It has platform independent interface and underneath implementations for each platform.

**UI backend** - used for drawing basic widgets like combo boxes and windows. It exposes a generic interface that is not platform specific. Underneath it uses the operating system user interface methods.

**JavaScript interpreter** - Used to parse and execute the JavaScript code.
Data storage. This is a persistence layer. The browser needs to save all sorts of data on the hard disk, for examples, cookies. The new HTML specification (HTML5) defines 'web database' which is a complete (although light) database in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

In fact the ones you called are not languages (HTML/CSS/) except js. Html and css are just markups and formatting standards. The are intercepted using engines in web browsers bases on standards. But js is a language that has its logic and syntax and semantic and intercepted using separated engine.

Comment: You're misusing the term "language".  They are languages, but they aren't executable code.

Comment: HTML is an acronym for HyperText Markup Language, not a programming language. It is generally used only for creating the layout of a web document. http://infospace.ischool.syr.edu/2012/04/05/why-html-is-not-a-programming-language/

Comment: @persianDeveloper I know that, but its still a language.

Answer (score 0):

YES, your browser compiles or interprets and Javascript. You can debate if it's compiling or interpreting. See: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ptorr/archive/2003/09/14/56184.aspx

Your browser interprets HTML/CSS with its rendering engine:
http://taligarsiel.com/Projects/howbrowserswork1.htm#Rendering_engines

Comment: It's interpreting. No debate needed. However, Microsoft does come with something called the `jsc`, where they implement **their own version** of JavaScript in a compiler.

Comment: TraceMonkey is a compiler, albeit a JIT compiler: https://wiki.mozilla.org/JavaScript%3aTraceMonkey

Answer (score 0):

by using the browser rendering engine..

A full-featured browser engine is hugely complex. Blink, Gecko, WebKit—these are millions of lines of code each. Even younger, simpler rendering engines like Servo and WeasyPrint are each tens of thousands of lines. building the dom, parsering html,css,js and painting accordingly are some features handled by the engine.

When the rendering engine gets the contents of the requested document from the networking layer. It will start parsing the HTML document and turn the tags to DOM nodes in a tree called the "content tree". It will parse the style data, both in external CSS files and in style elements. The styling information together with visual instructions in the HTML will be used to create another tree - the render tree.
Engines may wait for all data to be received before rendering a page, or may begin rendering before all data is received.

What does a  render tree contain?
It contains rectangles with visual attributes like color and dimensions. The rectangles are in the right order to be displayed on the screen.
After the render tree has been constructed, it goes through a "layout" process. Here each node is given the exact coordinates where it should appear on the screen. The next stage is painting - the render tree will be traversed and each node will be painted using the UI backend layer.
After the painting you get to see your final requested data on the web page.